# Problem with verbatim in a beamer frame

Tags: beamer, verbatim

It seems that `verbatim` is not working properly. It produce an error and the output is not as I expected. Here is the latex code

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`==12 }

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{verbatim}

Call:
glm(formula = propn.dead ~ conc, family = binomial(link = logit), 
    weights = number)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.5941  -0.3944   0.8329   1.2592   1.5940  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -60.717      5.181  -11.72   <2e-16 ***
conc          34.270      2.912   11.77   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 284.202  on 7  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  11.232  on 6  degrees of freedom
AIC: 41.43

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
\end{verbatim}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Add `fragile` option to the frame

Comment: Have never used it before. Can you please give me the code?

Comment: I think @percusse means `\begin{frame}[fragile]` and `\end{frame}`.

Comment: Or use `beamer`'s own `semivarbatim` environment instead of `verbatim`, as in `\begin{ssemiverbatim}...\end{semiverbatim}`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error is because you have to declare the frame as `[fragile]` due to the presence of verbatim code.

To get a good fit you can reduce the size of the font and you can use another font. To reduce the size of the font you can use `\footnotesize` or `\scriptsize` in the frame. If you add `\usepackage[scaled]{beramono}` to the preamble it will use the beramono font for the monospaced fonts used in verbatim. The beramono use less space than the default monospaced font.

Look the images below the difference.

### Using default font and `\footnotesize`

[image]

### Using Beramono font and `\footnotesize`

[image]

### The Modified Code

Here is the code using beramono font and `\footnotesize` (produces the second image)

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`==12 }

\usepackage[scaled]{beramono} %sets the beramono font. Just comment this line to get the default font back

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile]
\footnotesize %change the font size. You can \scriptsize to get a smaller font.
\begin{verbatim}
Call:
glm(formula = propn.dead ~ conc, family = binomial(link = logit), 
    weights = number)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.5941  -0.3944   0.8329   1.2592   1.5940  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -60.717      5.181  -11.72   <2e-16 ***
conc          34.270      2.912   11.77   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 284.202  on 7  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  11.232  on 6  degrees of freedom
AIC: 41.43

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
\end{verbatim}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

It´s a matter of your personal taste now. :-)

Comment: See also the blog entry by Pieter Belmans on the reason for `fragile`: [Why LaTeX beamer needs fragile when using verbatim](https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=4556)

Answer (score 3):

In addition to specifying the option `[fragile]` when starting the `frame`, you will need to issue the command `\scriptsize` -- for a 30% linear reduction in font size -- in order to make the verbatim material fit in the frame.

[image]

```
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
\usetheme{Madrid}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}

\usepackage{beamerthemesplit}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%%\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{natbib} 
\usepackage[turkish]{babel}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\AtBeginDocument{\catcode`==12 }

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[fragile] %% option "fragile" is new
\scriptsize  %%  new instruction
\begin{verbatim}

Call:
glm(formula = propn.dead ~ conc, family = binomial(link = logit), 
    weights = number)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-1.5941  -0.3944   0.8329   1.2592   1.5940  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  -60.717      5.181  -11.72   <2e-16 ***
conc          34.270      2.912   11.77   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 284.202  on 7  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance:  11.232  on 6  degrees of freedom
AIC: 41.43

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 4
\end{verbatim}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: +1. Another option (that I just suggested in a comment to the question) is to use `beamer`'s own `semiverbatim` instead of `verbatim`; the former doesn't require an explicit `fragile` for the frame.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina - Thanks. I just tried out `semiverbatim`, am I'm afraid the output looks awful for the case at hand if `fragile` is *not* specified as well. (Basically, `semiverbatim` without `fragile` seems to ignore line breaks that aren't immediately followed by a second line break.) Since `semiverbatim` differs from `verbatim` only in the treatment of `{`, `}`, and `\ `, there would seem to be little advantage in the present situation, right?

Comment: Yes, you're right. Both `verbatim` and `semiverbatim` are very basic verbatim environments; an option using the powerful `listings` package could be a better possibility here.